# How to make Angular ui grid expand rows initially based on data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info) to show a list of data and on display of the grid I am trying to expand some of the rows depending on the data.

I am trying to do this in the `onRegisterApi` event:

```
scope.GridOptions = {
    data: properties,
    columnDefs: 
    [
        { name: "Full Address", field: "FullAddress" },
        { name: "Suburb", field: "Suburb" },
        { name: "Property Type", field: "PropertyType" },
        { name: "Price", field: "Price", cellFilter: 'currency'},
        { name: "Status", field: "Status" },
        { name: "Sale Type", field: "SaleType" }, 
        { name: "Date Created", field: "CreateDate", cellFilter: "date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mma'"}
    ],
    expandableRowTemplate: 'template.html',
    expandableRowHeight: 200,
    onRegisterApi: (gridApi) => 
    {
        gridApi.expandable.expandAllRows();
    }
};
```

The problem is `gridApi.expandable.expandAllRows()` expands all of the grouped sections.  I see there is a [`expandRow`](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.treeBase.service:uiGridTreeBaseService#methods_expandrow) function, but I am not sure how to use it in place of the [`expandAllRows`](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.treeBase.service:uiGridTreeBaseService#methods_expandallrows) function.  I really would like to expand the group that has the column `Status` set to a particular value.  Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to handle expanding of selective rows. I have created a Plunker link (http://plnkr.co/edit/CSaROQqKxYnkoxm2Tl6b?p=preview) where I am expanding all the even rows. In a similar way, you can iterate over the array and expand the required rows.

Include:
    "`$timeout`" dependency in the controller

To expand first row:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var rows = $scope.gridApi.grid.rows;
    var entity = (rows.length && rows[0]) ? rows[0].entity : null;
    $scope.gridApi.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(entity);
  });
```

Comment: Good answer.  It helped me figure out where I need to go in my code, but it doesn't check the existing data values of each row.  Can you update you answer to include this? Also, why did you use the `$timeout` function?

Comment: What do you mean by existing values? I understood them as the values that are in the array at the time of rendering the table.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for.  Your example uses the index and none of the data from the model

Comment: Your data is nothing but rows. You can access each row content using rows[i].entity.name, rows[i].entity.phone etc.

Comment: it is giving me this error:
``cnl.ctrl.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleRowExpansion' of undefined``

Comment: I guess that you have missed including 'ui.grid.expandable' module

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my time.

Comment: When i click Expand All, its not working correctly. It's showing blank rows. Is this a virtualization problem ? any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

May be I am late to answer.
But it may help others.

I have taken the same plunker example as SaiGiridhar posted, but modified

```
$timeout(function() {
    var rows = $scope.gridApi.grid.rows;
    for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
      if(i%2 === 0){
        var entity = (rows.length && rows[i]) ? rows[i].entity : null;
        $scope.gridApi.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(entity);
      }
    }
});
```

to

```
$scope.$$postDigest(function() {
    var rows = $scope.gridApi.grid.rows;
    for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
      if(i%2 === 0){
        var entity = (rows.length && rows[i]) ? rows[i].entity : null;
        $scope.gridApi.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(entity);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the benifit of using `$$postDigest`?